# Почему не устанавливается rxjs?

Tags: angular2, npm, rxjs

Странная ситуация, `rxjs` вроде устанавливается, но при попытке его использовать, говорит что он не установлен. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это может быть и как исправить?

```
$ sudo npm install -g rxjs
+ rxjs@5.5.6
updated 1 package in 5.78s
Mac-mini-Pavel:pipes pavel$ sudo npm i bootstrap --save
npm WARN @angular/common@5.2.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@5.2.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@5.2.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@5.2.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

`ng --version` возвращает:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.2
Node: 8.9.4
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.1
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

установи его без -g

`npm install core-js

npm install rxjs`